# Tomcat does not prompt certificate for web application (OpenAM)

Tags: tomcat, ssl, certificate, openam

I have been trouble shooting my set up of  OpenAM for a while, still could not make it work as wanted. I wanted OpenAM to be able to to do OCSP validate authenticating user through my own copy of EJBCA. Therefore, I need tomcat prompt for user certificate and pass it to OpenAM. Visiting OpenAM from HTTPS is fine, and user can login using password (root realm in OpenAM). However, tomcat does not prompt for user certificate when visiting the realm designed for certificate login (a sub-realm in OpenAM which require certificate). Anyone has any thought on it? Here is a fragment of `server.xml` of my Tomcat configuration related to SSL:

```
    <Connector port="8181" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8445" />
    <Connector port="8445" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           keystoreFile="/opt/sso/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/conf/keystore"
           keystorePass="password"
           truststoreFile="/opt/sso/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/conf/keystore"
           truststorePass="password"
           clientAuth="want" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

There is no change to `web.xml` file in my case. Thanks.

Here is the output of `openssl s_client -connect FQDN:8445` per Bernhard's suggestion

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 CN = leopardrootCA
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=ncw01271123114/OU=ouname/O=O-name/L=j/ST=a/C=us
   i:/CN=leopardrootCA
 1 s:/CN=leopardrootCA
   i:/CN=leopardrootCA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDlzCCAwC--too_long_too_show
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/CN=ncw01271123114/OU=ouname/O=O-name/L=j/ST=a/C=us
issuer=/CN=leopardrootCA
---
Acceptable client certificate CA names
/CN=leopardrootCA
/CN=ncw0127114/OU=ouname/O=O-name/L=j/ST=a/C=us
---
SSL handshake has read 2097 bytes and written 403 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA
Server public key is 1024 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: 53309AA15C218F41330C077476A3BDAE352CAFD84A503A281EA09AE884BA73D9
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: EF5016A9D8236A704313720FC2E1A1B9FAC47A744F6A9B53E80BBEF8D1141476E050A71F3C50498ABEE1F790A2D76891
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1395694241
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
```

Comment: Are there any CA certificate entries in your truststore (which also seems to be your keystore)?

Comment: Bruno, thanks for asking. I did import rootCA.pem file into both java trust store and tomcat keystore suing the following:  [install into Java]  keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -alias centerwideroot -file ../certificates/CenterWideRoot.pem -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts    [install into Tomcat]keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -alias centerwideca -file ../certificates/CenterWideRoot.pem -keystore ./conf/keystore   [Install CA signed into tomcat]keytool -importcert -alias server-cert -file ../certificates/singed.pem -keystore /opt/sso/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/conf/keystore

Comment: either you troubleshoot this on network layer or on JSEE layer (JVM's SSL implementation), http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Debug. 

on network layer you may look at an output of openssl s_client -connect FQDN:8445

Sitenode, you can only target cert-based for a sub-realm if you have separate listeners for Tomcat.

Comment: @BernhardThalmayr, I have put the output of openssl_s_client in the original post, could you please help me trouble shoot it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the following handshake message

```
Acceptable client certificate CA names
/CN=leopardrootCA
/CN=ncw0127114/OU=ouname/O=O-name/L=j/ST=a/C=us
```

Tomcat is asking for client certificates and only accepts certificates which are issued by one of those certificate authorities.

Comment: Bernhard, thanks for your lead. The real problem is I do have a client certificate issued by /CN=leopardrootCA in Firefox certificates.

Comment: then go ahead an do a network trace (e.g. using Wireshark or Microsoft Network Monitor) and look at the SSL handshake messages

Comment: Bernhard, Good lead.I have found the problem.When I define the client certificate profile in EJBCA I did not choose specific extended key usage. I fixed it by choosing client authentication,SSH Client and MS smart Card logon I do not know which one takes effect but certainly one of them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem is related to the [`extended key usage`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.12) of client certificate. It worth try if someone has the same situation as me. Thanks for all who helped.

Copied from my comment:

- *I have found the problem.When I define the client certificate profile in EJBCA I did not choose specific extended key usage. I fixed it by choosing client authentication,SSH Client and MS smart Card logon I do not know which one takes effect but certainly one of them.*

Comment: client auth   
is the needed extension; sorry I was not aware that you would not have certs for client auth although you wanted to perform SSL client auth.